# the right way of connecting the if-clause with other clauses

Tags: grammar, punctuation, syntax

What's the right way of connecting the if-clause with other clauses in a complex sentence?

Should I just use a comma?:

> If there are still some issues that haven’t not been dealt with over
> one **month, we** feel entitled to file a complaint.

Or should I use comma and the word "then"?:

> If there are still some issues that haven’t not been dealt with over
> one **month, then we** feel entitled to file a complaint.

Or should I just do it without any commas and words?:

> If there are still some issues that haven’t not been dealt with over
> one **month we** feel entitled to file a complaint.

Answer (score 1):

A comma helps and is considered good punctuation.  This is true especially when the clauses are long.  A comma is not generally needed if the condition clause follows the main clauase (as in this sentence).

The conjunction "then" is normally optional. It is used quite often, and can help to make your writing more clear, or for emphasis. But it is rarely required. See https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6724/can-i-use-an-if-clause-without-then